# Buscar datos que contengan un dato en común repetido y eliminar

Tags: sql, sql-server

Quiero buscar en una tabla clientes que estén repetidos pero que tengan repetidos un dato en especifico, por ejemplo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La tabla esta llena así por ejemplo, entonces quiero un query que me busque los clientes que tengan el campo ESTADO repetido, y al identificarlos borrar uno de ellos, en este caso el que tenga fecha más reciente que sería un con `max`

```
SELECT c.NombreCliente, COUNT(c.Estado) FROM Clientes c GROUP BY c.NombreCliente
    HAVING COUNT(c.Estado)>1;
```

Este es el query que tengo pero no sé si estará bien, y para borrar quería saber si solo se aplica un `delete from` y esta consulta dentro de un paréntesis.

Comment: qué motor de base de datos estás usando?

Comment: y lo probaste? no parece tener ningun error...

Comment: @gbianchi la consulta que está haciendo no borra ninguna fila, ni está identificando el más reciente, ni tampoco si el estado está repetido. Por otro lado Marco, quieres quedarte con una fila para cada cliente/estado?, o quieres borrar una fila?

Comment: la pregunta es si el query esta bien... ese query indica si un cliente tiene estados repetidos, que es lo que escribio en la pregunta... ;) @Lamak, me limite a lo que escribio... en realidad a la pregunta le falta de todo, y sobre todo que OP lo pruebe...

Comment: pero no indica si un cliente tiene estados repetidos necesariamente, porque va a mostrar las filas en que un cliente tiene más de un estado simplemente, independiente si está repetido o no

Comment: bien viste, le falta un campo al group by...

Comment: Le falta un `DISTINCT` en el `COUNT` del `HAVING`. Independiente de eso, Marco tiene que aclarar qué es lo que quiere hacer finalmente y qué motor de base de datos y versión está usando

Comment: El motor de Base de datos es SQL, lo que requiero es una búsqueda de los clientes que tengan el campo ESTADO repetido, al realizar la sentencia anterior me trae clientes que tienen estado distinto

Comment: Luego de identificar esos clientes que tienen unicamente el campo estado repedito, borrar una fila de esos 2, queriando borrar poniendo como ejemplo la imagen el Max(FechaCambioEstado)

Comment: SQL es el lenguaje de consultas. Estás usando Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL u otro motor?. Y la consulta que hiciste NO trae necesariamente clientes con estados distintos

Comment: y qué pasa si el estado está repetido 3 o más veces?, a eso me refiero. Entonces quieres quedarte con el que tiene fecha de cambio más antiguo?

Comment: Sql Server, y en esa tabla no hay cliente con estado repetido 3 o mas veces, unicamente 2 veces, como seria modificar esa consulta para que unicamente me traiga los clientes que tengan el campo ESTADO igual, asi como se muestra en la imagen

Comment: Es correcto quiero quedarme con el de fecha mas antigua

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con la siguiente consulta puedes eliminar la fila con el dato más nuevo de la tabla:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NombreCliente, Estado 
                          ORDER BY FechaCambioEstado DESC) RN,
        COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY NombreCliente, Estado) N
    FROM dbo.Clientes
)
DELETE FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
AND N > 1;
```

Comment: Justo lo que necesitaba